# Value not returned to observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

Can anyone explain to my why this doesn't work and why it sends multiple network request:

```
public data$: Observable<Data> = of({ data1: 0, data2: [] });
private skip$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
private readonly take = 10;

...

this.data$ = this.skip$.pipe(
  switchMap((skip: number) => {
    return zip(
      this.data$, 
      this.dataService.getData(skip, this.take)
    ).pipe(
      map((d) => {
        return Object.assign({
          data1: d[1].data1,
          data2: [...d[0].data2, ...d[1].data2],
        });
      })
    );
  })
);
```

I am subscribing to data$ in the template with an async pipe.

I am assuming that it has something to do with the fact the I am using the data$ observable in the zip but also returning the output to data$. But I would like to do that.

Comment: please show definition of `this.dataService.getData(skip, this.take)`

Answer (score 0):

you have created recursion - I see warning  `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I would change to this:

```
const dataServiceGetData = (skip, take) => of({ data1: 0, data2: [] });

data$ = skip$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(data$),
  switchMap(([skip, data]) => zip(of(data), dataServiceGetData(skip,take))),
  map(([initial, newData]) => ({
    data1: newData.data1,
    data2: [...initial.data2, ...newData.data2]
  }))
);
```

or even to this:

```
data$ = skip$.pipe(
  switchMap((skip) => dataServiceGetData(skip,take)),
  withLatestFrom(data$),
  map(([newData, initial]) => ({
    data1: newData.data1,
    data2: [...initial.data2, ...newData.data2]
  }))
);
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this always updates the list with new values instead of adding the newly fetched values to the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong:

```js
// You've defined data$ here
public data$: Observable<Data> = of({ data1: 0, data2: [] });
private skip$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
private readonly take = 10;

// You then redefine data again, and pass it into itself recursively below.
this.data$ = this.skip$.pipe(
  switchMap((skip: number) => {
    return zip(
      this.data$, // <------- passing this.data into itself
      this.dataService.getData(skip, this.take)
    ).pipe(
      map((d) => {
        return Object.assign({
          data1: d[1].data1,
          data2: [...d[0].data2, ...d[1].data2],
        });
      })
    );
  })
);
```

What I think you're trying todo:

```js
public class DataOverTime {
  latest: Data;
  all: Data[];
  constructor(latest: Data, all: Data[]) {
    this.latest = latest;
    this.all = all;
  }
}

private _data = new BehaviorSubject<DataOverTime>(new DataOverTime(null, []));
public data$ = this._data as Observable<DataOverTime>;
private _skip = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
private readonly take = 10;

this._skip.pipe(
  switchMap((skip: number) => {
    return this.dataService.getData(skip, this.take).pipe(
      map((newData) => {
        const oldData = this._data.getValue();
        return new DataOverTime(newData, [...oldData.all, newData]);
      })
    );
  })
).subscribe(this._data);
```